# Redux await async thunk keeps going

Tags: redux, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

I'm currently using redux / redux-thunk to fetch a user using api-sauce like so

```
let authToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@TSQ:auth_token')

if (authToken) {
  store.dispatch(fetchUser(authToken))
  console.log('show login screen')
  // dont worry, if the token is invalid, just send us to onboarding (api determines this)
  loggedInView()
} else {
  Onboarding ()
}

....

export const fetchUser = authToken => async dispatch => {
  console.log('dispatching auth token')

  console.log('here goes request')
  let res = await api.get(`/auth/${authToken}`);

  if (res.ok) {
    console.log('have the user')
    dispatch(
      setUser(res.data)
    )
  } else {
    dispatch({
      type: 'SET_USER_DEFAULT'
    })
}
```

}

When this code is ran, the user is still loading and the console.logs are not in order

```
`dispatching auth token`
`here goes request`
`show login screen`
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the actual call to `store.dispatch(fetchUser(authToken))` is synchronous - the `dispatch()` method [is not asynchronous](https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatch-action), so the logging "show login screen" will occur immediately after execution of the `fetchUser()` method.

If you want `loggedInView()` to be executed after a response is returned from your network request (ie the call to the async method `api.get()`), then you could consider refactoring your code in the following way:

```
if (authToken) {
  store.dispatch(fetchUser(authToken))
  // Remove navigation from here
} else {
  Onboarding ()
}
```

And then:

```
export const fetchUser = authToken => async dispatch => {
  console.log('dispatching auth token')

  console.log('here goes request')
  let res = await api.get(`/auth/${authToken}`);

  if (res.ok) {
    console.log('have the user')

    // Occurs after network request is complete    
    console.log('show login screen')

    // Add navigation here to go to logged in view now that request is complete
    loggedInView()

    dispatch(
      setUser(res.data)
    )
  } else {
    dispatch({
      type: 'SET_USER_DEFAULT'
    })
}
```

Hope this helps!